# Volley request gives inaccurate response yet the link data is correct

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

I'm getting a problem with reading data from json url, the link is working fine, I added a log for the `getURL` method and when I click on the link from Monitor, the data on the browser are accurate..!! but the response is NOT..!

I wanna filter the Completed orders from the request,  it does filter normally with this code, but the response data is not updated ..! if for example I change the status from backend or added a new order for this user, the new changes don't show..! the link itself has correct data but the response from the link is not,, the only way to get the new correct data is if I manually clear the app data then login again... only then the response gets updated..!?

The codes below might not help you since I doubt the problem are from them...!

any thoughts...!?

---

**The OrderRepository class which has a method that makes the request**

```
  public static void fetchOrders(final Context context, final DataFetch fetcher) {

    final Customer customer;

    customer = Hawk.get("user");

    int userID = customer.getID();


    final RequestQueue requestQueue;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
  final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getURL(FETCH_ORDERS_URI, userID), null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<OrderPresenter>>() {}.getType();
                    try {
                        List<OrderPresenter> TheOrders;

                        TheOrders = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONArray("orders").toString(), listType);
                        ArrayList<OrderPresenter> result = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (OrderPresenter record : TheOrders) {
                            Log.i("Statuses_Gson1", record.getStatus());
                            while (record.getStatus().equals("completed")) {
                                result.add(record);
                                fetcher.onResponse(result);
                                break;
                            }
                         }

                  }else {
                    Toasty.error(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_noOrders), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        fetcher.onErrorResponse(e);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "catched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    fetcher.onErrorResponse(error);
                }
            });



    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

**DataFeach Calss (this is gonna be a help class)**

```
abstract public class DataFetch {
public abstract void onResponse(ArrayList<OrderPresenter> response);

public void onErrorResponse(Exception exception){

};
}
```

**My fragment class which holds the recyclerview**

```
  .....
   ...
   .

    List<OrderPresenter> modelData = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
           recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

    OrderRepository.fetchOrders(getActivity(), new DataFetch() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ArrayList<OrderPresenter> data) {

           OrdersDataAdapter  adapter = new OrdersDataAdapter(data, getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           // recyclerView.invalidate();

        }
    });

  .... 
  ...
  .
```

**----- UPDATE ------**

it seems that the cached data don't get cleared when new request is made..! so I solved it with this line =>

```
 requestQueue.getCache().clear();
```

Comment: could you provide us with a sample of output

Comment: You have a while loop with an immediate break. Use an if statement, please. And your question doesn't show a [mcve] and I think your "help class" isn't do anything

Comment: the purpose of the helper class, is when using another request, I will be calling the DataFetch class, but the problem with I think is the first parameter in the OnResponse method, it should not be specific to the OrderPresenter, but any General type of List, and when the method gets called in a request, I will define what type of list I want..! I tires using List<E> but it didn't work>! any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your filter is correct... You only grab one item

```
final Customer customer = Hawk.get("user");
int userID = customer.getID();

final Gson gson = new Gson();
final Type listType = new TypeToken<List<OrderPresenter>>() {}.getType();

final RequestQueue requestQueue = 
Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getURL(FETCH_ORDERS_URI, userID), null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    List<OrderPresenter> orders = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONArray("orders").toString(), listType);
                    ArrayList<OrderPresenter> result = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (OrderPresenter record : orders) {
                        Log.i("Statuses_Gson1", record.getStatus());
                        if (record.getStatus().equals("completed")) {
                            result.add(record);
                        }
                     }

                    fetcher.onResponse(result); // this is after the for loop
```

Your while loop was pointless and you appear to have some random else statement in there without an if

You also should not be creating a new adapter on every response.

```
final List<OrderPresenter> modelData = new ArrayList<>();
final RecyclerView   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

OrdersDataAdapter  adapter = new OrdersDataAdapter(modelData, getActivity());
adapter.setMode(Attributes.Mode.Single);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

OrderRepository.fetchOrders(getActivity(), new DataFetch() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ArrayList<OrderPresenter> data) {
         modelData.clear();
         modelData.addAll(data);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       // recyclerView.invalidate();

    }
});
```

Comment: you were right, the filter wasn't working correctly due to my stupidity for choosing a while loop, I saw some code in github a while back which a while loop use to filter something.. so I thought it might work here, but using "If" is more sense, thx for that..!

Now for the problem I was facing, It didn't solve when I adjust the Fragment class code as you showed me..! but it did solve another issue I was having regarding the SwipeRefreshLayout, so thx a lot for that, it make sense now..!

I problem I was having solved after some digging with line => requestQueue.getCache().clear();

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can make a timer that requests every 1 min or something like that
and dont forget to update the adapter `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in every request

**UPDATE**

In order to avoid much requests,
There is something Called GCM this is a Google cloud messaging, i have old data Google cloud messaging has been implemented with firebase, well, use GCM and then in your android app use BroadCast receiver in order to handle the messages which are come from server